# Is there a way to add multiple horizontal lines to a plot with different symbology and a legent?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-hline

I need to add horizontal lines (similar to geom_hline) to a plot but retain the ability to add symbology (e.g. different dashed or dotted line) to each and have them appear in a legend. The y-intercept of each comes from the "Concentration" variable and the label needs to come from "Type". I've created an example dataset at the bottom of the question but the one I'm working with is a lot larger, with about 30 different Pesticides and up to 4 Types within each. I am hoping to split and sapply to automate plotting across the entire dataset.

Here is the plot code that I've tried so far and you can see the geom_hline works (as in, the lines appear on the plot), but it doesnt give the ability to change symbology of each or add a legend. Please ignore the box plots and jitter - they arent relevant to this question.

Is there a way i can add these lines to the plot, each with different symbology and a legend to capture that?

Thanks in advance

```
Plot2 <- ggplot(PestDat, aes(x=factor(Phyla), y=Conc_ug)) +
  geom_boxplot(color="dark gray", fill = 'dark gray', alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = Pathway), height=.3, width=.3, size = 1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') +
  geom_hline(data = PestDat,aes(yintercept = Concentration),linetype="dashed") +
  labs(x = "Phyla", y = "Log10 Concentration (µg/L)") +
   labs(title = (unique(ToxDat_Diuron$Pesticide)),
         subtitle = "Do we want a subtitle for the plot?",
        caption = "Source: Citation, Reliability ?? ")
           Plot2
```

[image]

Sample data

```
PestDat <- data.frame(
     Pest = c("Diuron","Diuron","Diuron","Diuron","Atrazine"),
     Type = c("PC99","PC95","PC90","PC80","ETV"),
     Concentration = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.7),
     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can put the `linetype` aesthetic inside the `aes()` term to make it use the variable from the data to categorize the type of line. Note that `linetype` wants a discrete variable, so in this case I used A-B-C.

```
ggplot(PestDat, aes(x=factor(Pest), y=Concentration)) +
  geom_boxplot(color="dark gray", fill = 'dark gray', alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_jitter(aes(shape = Type), height=.3, width=.3, size = 1.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10') +
  labs(x = "Phyla", y = "Log10 Concentration (µg/L)",
       subtitle = "Do we want a subtitle for the plot?") +
  geom_hline(data = data.frame(y_int = c(0.6,0.9, 1.1),
                               type = c("C","B","A")),
             aes(yintercept = y_int, linetype = type))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jon Spring! This code has worked to fix the symbology but I still can't get the legend to appear. I'll keep working on it to see if I can figure it out but if i give up I might reach out again to see if you can help. Thank you!

Comment: It might help to edit your question to show a reproducible example of what you're trying, with what sample data, and what result you're getting. One thing to look out for, ggplot2 will combine legends if they have the same name, so Type and type in my example are separate, but if both were Type it would try to combine them.